# Inserting a Worksheet between two specific worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have created an excel macro which allows a user to insert a new client and based off the clients name a worksheet is created. How I have this created is by using the following code: `Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Template")
    Sheets("Template (2)").Visible = True
    Sheets("Template (2)").Name = ClientAbbrev`

So what this does is create a copy of the template sheet which is hidden and creates a new tab which is named after the client abbreviation. This new 'entry' is generally inserted between two 'book-ends' - Template and Template End. So the newly inserted tab would go here:
Template, NEW TAB HERE, Template End.

Now that I've hidden both Template and Template End, when I Insert New Clients instead of having it appear like above, it appears like this:
Template, Template End, NEW TAB HERE.

This is a problem as I have a summing array which takes all the data between the Start and End Tabs and now it doesn't seem to work unless the Book-End Tab isn't hidden. Can anyone shed some light on this or tell me how to write a macro to insert tabs specifically between those two tabs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub addNewSheet()
    Dim t As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Set t = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    t.Copy After:=t
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(t.Index + 1)
    With ws
        .Visible = True
        .Name = "New client"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the help. There's an issue however with the template end being renamed as template (3) constantly which seems to mess up some values when I some them due to the range having changed. Can this be addressed? :)

Comment: Actually Don't worry Paul - it was a mistake on my part. I forgot to comment out a incrementer I had which kept renaming the set range. Thanks very much! Just to further my understanding could you explain what the impact of t.index + 1 does?

Comment: By using `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(t.Index + 1)` the next lines don't rely on the sheet name that Excel automatically assigns to new sheets, instead it gets a reference to the newly created sheet by using the sheet index: If "Template" sheet has index 1, the new sheet will get index 2 (Copy After:=Sheet-with-index-1), so "ws" is the new sheet, with index 2

Comment: Okay, nope. The same issue has appeared again where my Template End is being renamed to template (2). The problem is that I have a Summary Worksheet behind both Template 1 and 2 Which sums up all the values between those tabbed worksheets i.e. Template 1, NEW ENTRY, NEW ENTRY, NEW ENTRY, Template 2 (End). As the fields on the templates are all the same I then SUM it up. However with the Template 2 END now having its named changed to Template (2)/(3) it messes up the summed calculation. Is there anything you can advise for me to solve this?

Comment: There might be 2 ways to solve the issue: 1. what is the exact name of the template sheet to be copied? (I'll update my answer if this will be consistent). 2 if you never delete the main template we can also use its .CodeName - in VBA editor, top left: sheet name before the brackets

Comment: Great - I look forward to learning! The exact name of the template sheet to be copied is "Template". The main template is never deleted as all subsequent copies are copied off this template. What I do change in your code (if I use it) is that I have the .Name = ClientAbbrev. This is a defined variable which holds the client abbreviation entered by the individual.

Comment: How do you populate the summing array

Comment: Don't worry about it Paul - I was playing around with it more and I think by default, Excel Won't let you insert a new tab into two tabs which are hidden. As it's a small thing which doesn't impact the overall functionality - I'll leave it alone for now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ok, but if what you found is true then all you need to do to is turn off screen updating, make all tabs visible, insert the new tab where you want, hide the sheets, and turn screen updating back on

Comment: Hi Paul, but this wouldn't work as I continually insert new clients. The user of this will not want to make all tabs visible, insert the new tab where I want and then hide all the sheets again. I've managed to solve it by having the Template End Tab unhidden, which allows the new entries to be inserted in front of it. Which in turn allows the summary tab to correctly calculate and update :) Thanks for your help though!